# Why isn't this Ruby hash what I thought it would be?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have this code:

```
$ze = Hash.new( Hash.new(2) )

$ze['test'] = {0=> 'a', 1=>'b', 3 => 'c'}

$ze[5][0] = 'one'
$ze[5][1] = "two"

puts $ze
puts $ze[5]
```

And this is the output:

```
{"test"=>{0=>"a", 1=>"b", 3=>"c"}} 
{0=>"one", 1=>"two"}
```

Why isn't the output:

```
{"test"=>{0=>"a", 1=>"b", 3=>"c"}, 5=>{0=>"one", 1=>"two"}} 
{0=>"one", 1=>"two"}
```

?

Comment: Do not use global variables, they are ugly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `$ze[5][0] = xxx` you are first calling the getter `[]` of `$ze`, then calling the setter `[]=` of `$ze[5]`. See [Hash's API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

If `$ze` does not contain a key, it will return its default value that you initialized with `Hash.new(2)`.

```
$ze[5][0] = 'one'
# in detail
$ze[5] # this key does not exist,
       # this will then return you default hash.
default_hash[0] = 'one'

$ze[5][1] = 'two'
# the same here
default_hash[1] = 'two'
```

You are not adding anything to `$ze` but you are adding key/value pairs to its default hash.
That is why you can do this too. You will the same result as `$ze[5]`.

```
puts $ze[:do_not_exist]
# => {0=>"one", 1=>"two"}
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize you even could modify the default hash. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = Hash.new(2)
print "h['a'] : "; p h['a']

$ze = Hash.new( Hash.new(2) )
print '$ze[:do_not_exist]    : '; p $ze[:do_not_exist]
print '$ze[:do_not_exist][5] : '; p $ze[:do_not_exist][5]

$ze = Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key] = {}}
$ze['test'] = {0=> 'a', 1=>'b', 3 => 'c'}
$ze[5][0] = 'one'
$ze[5][1] = "two"
print '$ze : '; p $ze
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb
h['a'] : 2
$ze[:do_not_exist]    : {}
$ze[:do_not_exist][5] : 2
$ze : {"test"=>{0=>"a", 1=>"b", 3=>"c"}, 5=>{0=>"one", 1=>"two"}}
```